# Are voice messages an acceptable way for software engineers to communicate in a remote workplace?

Tags: software-industry, communication, slack

Imagine you work in a remote-first software engineering company, where written messages via Slack are the only established way of asynchronous communication. You find that a newcomer often uses in-Slack voice messages instead of in-Slack written messages.

In my opinion, the disadvantage of voice messages is twofold, and immediately obvious:

- It forces the receiver to either read a bad transcript by the AI, or sit through 1-2 minutes of voice recording instead of spending 15 seconds reading a well-crafted text message.
- It robs the sender of the opportunity to organize their thoughts in a concise manner and make the output truly presentable, which would normally be easy via text.

What's the etiquette here?
Is it reasonable to expect the newcomer to adapt, or should the others get used to it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the voice messages. Are these via a messaging system, or do they leave a message on a seperate phone? In either case, maybe disabling that functionality may be the best way forward.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I've edited the question. Both the voice messages and the text messages are inside Slack

Comment: Is this is private messages or channels?

Comment: private messages

Comment: Did you try asking them? Or ask them to send a text message instead? You can't search a voice message reliably.

Comment: Note the sender can view both of those points as a disadvantages for written communication - it forces them to spend 5 minutes writing and editing a written message instead of spending 1-2 minutes leaving the voice recording, and it robs them of the opportunity to express themselves in a natural cadence that has nuances of expression that cannot easily be captured in the written word.

Comment: @Nelson nah...  that would require social interaction.

Comment: "sit through 1-2 minutes of voice recording" — how slowly are they speaking? "It robs the sender of the opportunity to organize their thoughts in a concise manner and make the output truly presentable, which would normally be easy via text" — That makes a lot of assumptions about what the sender finds easy. I've a dyslexic friend who sometimes finds communicating via voice messages easier than writing, and is perfectly succinct.

Comment: Is this person dyslexic?

Comment: voice messages suck for many reasons. Besides this, you ask *"expect the newcomer to adapt, or should the others"* - why should **one** newcomer make **many** others change their behavior?

Comment: Lots of people are able to "organize their thoughts" while speaking.  Some people have a hard time writing those "organize their thoughts" into the written word. You make an incorrect assumption about the spoken word. Case in point, I had problems finding a word, for "the spoken word" but if I was talking to you I wouldn't have had that problem.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'm guessing the difference is in the other direction - they may be speaking normal speed, but some of us can read way faster than people can talk.

Answer (score 41):

> What's the etiquette here?

You tell us. It's your team's Slack workspace, so your team makes the rules how it's to be used.

How do you do that?

- By establishing unwritten rules through example and precedent
- By talking to each other and coming to a consensus about what the rules should be
- If you are in a position that has that authority, by setting rules in a dictatorial fashion

Option one has apparently failed, and if you had option three, you probably wouldn't be posting this question.

So the best option would be to schedule a meeting with all Slack participants where everyone shares their experiences with the Slack channels, what forms of communication they find effective and what forms ineffective. Remember: no finger-pointing! Criticize the behavior, not the person. Don't say "I want Newcomer to stop posting voice messages", say "I don't like voice messages, because...".

Then, based on everyone's experiences, you can have a discussion on what rules and guidelines would make sense for your team's Slack usage.

After the meeting, you write down the rules you agreed on in a properly formatted document. You then send that document to everyone with a "if you disagree, speak now or forever hold your peace" warning, and then post it somewhere where people can look it up.

Comment: *By establishing unwritten rules through example and precedent* – Tbh even *written* rules would be a good idea here.

Comment: @csstudent1418 And how do you make written rules? Through either the 2nd or the 3rd bullet point of the same list.

Comment: If I were a newcomer and the boss held a meeting that was pretty unambiguously triggered by something I was doing, and my boss hadn't already talked to me about it, then I would find that pretty passive-aggresive.

Comment: Scheduling a meeting about it seems like a big escalation at this point. Shouldn't OP start with telling the newcomer that he prefers to receive text message than voice ones ?

Comment: If I'd be handed a paper/document titled "Slack Rules" when I join a team I'd be out before you can count to 3. Two mature adults should be able to figure out how they want to communicate together without having to draft up a "legal" document.

Comment: Remember that it takes a newcomer some time to figure out the unwritten rules and expectations, be it for Slack communication, lunch break times, or anything else around the office. Someone has to put an arm around the newcomer and walk him/her around the office (physically or virtually) explaining these rules on the first day (or at least within the first week). If that doesn't happen, it's likely that newcomer _will_ break many rules until he learns them after many painful faux pas. Therefore, some sort of "general expectations" doc is handy for remote workers.

Comment: If this guy is the only one doing this, then it seems like there already are "unwritten rules" that everyone else follows. So all that's needed is to educate the newbie.

Comment: @FreeMan In my experience, showing the newcomer around is much much better that any kind of a written document. Few things are more annoying than being told "all the rules are in this pile of docs,read up". Except the docs typically don't say the important things like "don't even think about ever touching Jack's keyboard" or "never ask Jill about her marriage" or "Bob always comes ten minutes late and that's fine,but nobody else is allowed to do the same".

Comment: Can't disagree, @TooTea, however, in todays remote work world, _something_ in writing is far better than _nothing_ in writing. Also, everyone involved must simply accept that the newbie _far_ longer figuring out all the unwritten rules than it used to.

Answer (score 27):

I can definitely see how this would be annoying. I like to listen to music or longform conversations whilst I work and to listen to a voicemail would require me to stop that, listen to it, and then start up again.

So my initial reaction would be along the lines of what [nvoigt suggested](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/190919/are-voice-messages-an-acceptable-way-for-software-engineers-to-communicate-in-a/190920#190920)...

However - there's one key bit of information that I don't have:

Have you asked the individual why they do this? I can't off the top of my head think of a good reason why, but seeing as it's pretty unusual, it suggests that there's a conversation there that should be had in case they have reason for doing it that way.

Comment: Quite possibly that person was told that text messages are unprofessional or some similar nonsense and understood it in the completely wrong way.

Comment: I think asking what's going on is DEFINITELY the right next step. When someone shows up so completely out of sync with what everyone else is doing, finding out what's going on is well worth your time before trying to push them in the preferred direction. Also, I long ago learned that asking questions can be a good way to get people to think about what they are doing without provoking defensive responses. That can in turn lead to an easier time fixing whatever is going on.

Comment: Maybe this person heard from or feels similar to all the people complaining about how it's hard to read tone in text, or how people often/usually only respond to some portion of a bigger message. Maybe they just don't like typing. Maybe they have a medical condition which makes typing some amount more difficult. But those are a wide range of reasons that may require different solutions (so asking isn't a terrible idea).

Comment: There can be good reasons. Some people are very bad at typing, either because they have a disability or injury or because they never bothered to learn a keyboard layout.

Comment: I used to have a colleague how would always instead copying and pasting text send an image. When I asked them why (because I was annoyed that I cannot copy and paste)  they said because it's easier for them to do that it's their established custom and it takes less time for them, because this is something they do automatically without thinking. So it was their inconvenience vs mine. I left it at that.

Comment: "I can't off the top of my head think of a good reason why..." I doubt this is the reason, as presumably the question would've mentioned it, but some people with disabilities *might( find it easier to send a voice message than a written one. That said, I used to work with someone who had muscular dystrophy to the extent that he used a fancy setup involving using his head as his primary input device (there was something attached to a cap he'd wear), and even he communicated via text when remote discussions took place. The guy was an amazing coder, btw, due to the macros he would create.

Comment: Another likely reason is just following habits from a different workplace, or from non-work communication.  My impression is that voice-messaging is on the rise again at the moment, especially in younger circles.

Comment: I frankly find it odd that you think that the priority of your workplace should be to allow you to continue listening to music over doing work-related activities.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine - I do my best work when I'm able to focus - music helps me fo that. Since I'm solely responsible for a number of systems, I don't need a lot of input from the rest of the team.

Comment: It might not be that unusual, some section of "the younger generation" actually seems more used to sending voice messages via chat apps than writing texts - which if a phone is your primary device for said chat app I can understand (it's setup more for voice communication than typed text imho). So they might just transfer that learned behaviour as natural to them. So maybe all it needs is a confrontation with the fact that in that group it is unusual (and potentially also having more drawbacks) contrary to their experiences so far.

Answer (score 13):

Just ask.

> "Sorry, could you type your question?  It helps me a lot later when I need to find this again"

That gives a reason too, that may not have been thought of.

Comment: Simple, direct, sensible.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 11):

> What's the etiquette here?

There is no etiquette. A voicemail is factually inferior to texting. We had audio messages for decades before phones could send simple texts and people thought "this is so annoying, we need to send texts to each other".

The only acceptable voice message is when one person is driving and is legally not allowed to touch their phone and text. That is the one exception.

Otherwise, you need to teach this person how to communicate effectively. That means gather their thoughts and then text.

Whether they want to type or dictate via voice is their choice. Any decent software has a speech-to-text feature in the messaging app. Normal smartphones can do it with no extras. So *they* can talk to their software all day long if they want to (or maybe if they have a disability). But their message needs to be text.

You need to educate them on this. They need to adapt. The same way that you would educate them if they used any other method from the 80s in their daily work life. Can you imagine them showing an actual slide show where the actual slide collection goes clickety-clack through the film projector instead of showing a PowerPoint file with a computer on a modern video projector? You would not wonder what the etiquette is. You would tell them to get into this century *and fast*.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145189/discussion-on-answer-by-nvoigt-are-voice-messages-an-acceptable-way-for-software); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 10):

> Is it reasonable to expect the newcomer to adapt, or should the others get used to it?

I think it's reasonable to expect them to adapt, but how you signal to them to change their behavior is important. The team could make a "text-only" rule, but it'll be more effective if you can show this person the benefit of changing their communication style. You may even be able to do this with a simple direct response instead of having to get the whole team together to decide on Slack etiquette.

The next time you get a voice message, try responding with:

> I'm sorry I can't listen to this right now because I'm in a meeting. Can you send a text version so I can get you a response quicker?

or

> Sorry I'm working from a coffee shop today and don't have headphones- can you type out your question here? The generated transcript is confusing so I'm skeptical it's correct.

Obviously don't lie, but you should be able to adapt some version of these responses to communicate to your coworker the benefits of text communication.

Comment: I would probability take the (slightly more passive-agressive) approach of replying to text messages immediately and listening to voice messages "when I need a break and it's convenient".

Comment: This is the best way to do it, way better than having a team meeting and implicitly making the new guy feel publicly targeted. I would also phrase the feedback more generally, i.e. say "it takes longer to respond to voice messages" rather than "it will take longer to respond to this voice message right now"